# How to get twitter search results as json with simple browser entry since Twitter v1.1?

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm working on the tuts+ jQuery course and am stuck on a lesson where the student is meant to retrieve json objects from a Twitter search.  The lesson advises the user to try the following search (in my browser address bar):

`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=tutspremium`

The error for this url is `{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}`.  I've worked that problem and found the following search:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=tuts%20premium`

I think this is the right string, but I get an auth error.  Further reading tells me I need authorization on all endpoints on the new Twitter API.

How do I set up authorization for getting tweets as json?  What if I don't want to be a member of Twitter?  Can I do Application only auth and build the creds in to my search function?  i.e.:

```
function getTweets( search ) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json, 
        data: { q: search },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        authCredentials
    });
});
```

Ideally I just want the simplest solution so I can go on learning deffereds from this course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to register your app [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) and get the consumer key and consumer secret. Then you will need to authenticate your request ([see the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)).