# Jquery Ajax Call always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to ger ajax response from below web url of twitter to but it returns always error.No way I am able to get it work.

URL is http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&ands=google?callback=?

I have added a callback at end.I suspect it's cross domain request so I have tried with **crossDomain:true** also.

So code is as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var weblink = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&ands=google?callback=?';
        $.ajax({
            url: weblink,
            dataType: 'jsonp',               
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok'); // this statement doesn't show up

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                // failed request; give feedback to user
                alert('error occured' + msg);
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });

        $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&ands=google?callback=?", function (result) {
            alert('success');
        });
    });
```

Here is the screenshot when I debug on F12.[image: Console Error]

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong happened.

Comment: is it about the version? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114204/message-the-twitter-rest-api-v1-is-no-longer-active-please-migrate-to-api-v1-1

Comment: If you had just pasted the URL you're using into the browser, you would have seen `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is about the version, as it says `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1` when you view this in your browser:  http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&ands=google?callback=?

Instead, you should have the following:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=mykeyword
```

You can check this discussion: [How to get twitter search results as json with simple browser entry since Twitter v1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495218/how-to-get-twitter-search-results-as-json-with-simple-browser-entry-since-twitte)